# Change Select statement to an update statement

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT A.GRPNO, A.EMPNO, A.DEPNO, A.PENDCD FROM EMPDEP A, EEDPELIG B
WHERE A.GRPNO=B.GRPNO
AND A.EMPNO=B.EMPNO
AND A.DEPNO=B.DEPNO
AND A.GRPNO = 6606 AND A.SPOUSE = 'T'
AND B.ELIGFLAG01 = 'T' AND SNAPTHRUDT ='DEC312999'
```

Our selection statement has been successful at pulling the information we need however we're new with SQL and are struggling to create an update statement that is replacing the "a.pendcd=0" to "a.pendcd=20" from the information in the select statement. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Why are you using archaic `JOIN` syntax?  Why are you using meaningless table aliases?

Comment: We're using a version of SQL Plus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

```
update a
a.pendcd=20
FROM EMPDEP A inner join EEDPELIG B
on A.GRPNO=B.GRPNO
AND A.EMPNO=B.EMPNO
AND A.DEPNO=B.DEPNO
AND A.GRPNO = 6606 AND A.SPOUSE = 'T'
AND B.ELIGFLAG01 = 'T' AND SNAPTHRUDT ='DEC312999'
where a.pendcd=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support `FROM` or `JOIN` in `UPDATE` (under most circumstances).

Just use `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE EMPDEP ed
    SET  . . .
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM EEDPELIG p
                  WHERE ed.GRPNO = p.GRPNO AND
                        ed.EMPNO= p.EMPNO AND
                        ed.DEPNO= p.DEPNO AND
                        p.ELIGFLAG01 = 'T'
                 )
          ed.GRPNO = 6606 AND
          ed.SPOUSE = 'T' AND
          ed.SNAPTHRUDT ='DEC312999';
```

It is unclear if the condition on `SNAPTHRUDT` is on the outer table or inner table.  If it is on `p`, then move it to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MERGE` statement as following:

Lets assume `EMPDEP` table has primary key which is `EMPDEP_UID`.

```
MERGE INTO EMPDEP TRG
USING
(SELECT A.EMPDEP_UID, A.PENDCD
   FROM EMPDEP A, EEDPELIG B
  WHERE A.GRPNO=B.GRPNO
    AND A.EMPNO=B.EMPNO
    AND A.DEPNO=B.DEPNO
    AND A.GRPNO = 6606 
    AND A.SPOUSE = 'T'
    AND B.ELIGFLAG01 = 'T' 
    AND SNAPTHRUDT ='DEC312999') SRC
ON (TRG.EMPDEP_UID = SRC.EMPDEP_UID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET TRG.PENDCD = 0
WHERE TRG.PENCD = 20;
```

You can use `unique keys` instead of `primary key` to identify the records to be updated. But it is safe to use `primary key` as `unique key` can contain nulls which can change the behaviour of our query.

Cheers!!